# Where do we post questions for Fictional novels?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question based on fictional novel (not sci-fi). Which section do I post it in? I don't find such section in stackexchange.

Comment: Why don't you tell us about the question?

Comment: Also, why not tell us which book?

Comment: In the absence of a stack exchange, you might try some of the chat rooms where such things may be on-topic/acceptable, or even try sites like Reddit (perhaps the book or literature subreddits).

Comment: For those encountering this page first, note that the question for which this is marked a duplicate has an updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Alas, the answer seems to be "Nowhere".

There was a Literature:SE Beta site but unfortunately it [collapsed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131397/why-did-literature-fail) from lack of interest.

There are a number of sites where you can ask **genre-specific** book questions (Religion, English Language Usage, philosophy) but no sites where you can ask *general* book questions.